# What should I use in instead of ~/.pam_environment (deprecated)?

Tags: environment-variables, pam-environment, 24.04

I used to put user-specific settings like `LANGUAGE` and `PAPERSIZE` in ~/.pam_environment, but [the manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man7/pam_env.7.html) and the warning emitted on login tells me:

> Due to problematic security this functionality is deprecated since the
> 1.5.0 version and will be removed completely at some point in the future.

Unfortunately that warning only tells me I am doing something wrong, not what I should do instead. I am guessing putting everything in [`~/.profile`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables) has minor differences, but that is what I should be using if/when the *deprecated* extra file is discontinued in Ubuntu?

Comment: I'd expect [systemd's `environment.d`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/environment.d.5.html) to be the prime candidate for everything that will involve systemd sessions (so should work fine for SSH, GUI logins etc.)

Comment: I have been using your `~/.profile` option for years. Please state the "minor differences"